# Cannot access variable in function in .rb file (sinatra)

Tags: ruby, function, sinatra

Right now, I have this code in my rb file. It works just fine:

```
project = PivotalTracker::Project.find(123456)  

get '/' do 
  @accepted = project.stories.all(:current_state => 'accepted').length
  @delivered = project.stories.all(:current_state => 'delivered').length
  @finished = project.stories.all(:current_state => 'finished').length    

  erb :home
end
```

I wanted to create a `totalStories` function to use instead of having 3 lengthy lines with redundant code.

So, I tried the following:

```
get '/' do 
  @accepted = totalStories('accepted')
  @delivered = totalStories('delivered')
  @finished = totalStories('finished')

  def totalStories(storyState)
    var estimate = project.stories.all(:current_state => storyState).length
    return var
  end

  erb :home
end
```

With this code, I get an error:

```
NoMethodError at /
undefined method `totalStories' for #<Sinatra::Application:0x007f89bae6c800>
```

Any tips on how to resolve this error? Thanks!

**UPDATE:**
I've moved the method outside of the `get` block but now I am getting a new error: `undefined local variable or method`project'`

the `project` variable is defined outside and above the method.

It's also worth noting that I use the `project` variable in other get blocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a helper instead:

```
get '/' do
  @accepted = total_stories('accepted') 
  @delivered = total_stories('delivered')
  @finished = total_stories('finished')

  erb :home
end

helpers do
  def total_stories(option)
    # project = PivotalTracker::Project.find(123456)
    project.stories.all(:current_state => option).length
  end
end
```

Adding the @sergey's answer, instead of the above code, you can avoid the `undefined method project` error by having a helper for that one object instead. Something like:

```
get '/' do
  # same code
end

def total_stories(option)
  project(12345).stories.all(:current_state => option).length
  # The project object here causes an error since it looks for a 
  # project method (yes, instead of object) under Sinatra's Base or Application
  # hence, we define the method inside the helpers block
end

helpers do
  def project(id)
    # Here goes the PivotalTracker find method for that particular ID.
  end

end
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: thank you kashyap! unfortunate even with the helpers (your first code block), i get "undefined local variable or method 'project'"  will try the second approach now.

Comment: ah, the first code block works only if i change `project` to become `$project` everywhere

Comment: although that seems like bad practice according to some articles i read?

Comment: In the first code block, have you defined what project is? I've added that as a comment. Try with the `#` removed.

Comment: ah, yes but i use `project` in other get blocks too.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create this function outside of the 'get' function?

```
def totalStories(storyState)
    project.stories.all(:current_state => storyState).length
end

get '/' do 
  @accepted = totalStories('accepted')
  @delivered = totalStories('delivered')
  @finished = totalStories('finished')

  erb :home
end
```

You may also shorten your totalStories function and leave only one statement since the last calculated result will be returned.

Comment: Ah, but now I encounter a new error: `undefined local variable or method 'project'`   project is a variable that is defined outside of the function (and also outside of the 'get').

Comment: (I can define `project` in the function, but it will be a duplicate line of code so it seems incorrect)

Comment: where exactly this variable is defined and what does it store?

Comment: at the top of my .rb file (after the 'require' lines). i'm using the Pivotal Tracker API (a project manager system) and it stores my project information (`project = PivotalTracker::Project.find(123456)`). i expected it to be accessible in the `totalStories` function.

Comment: you can make it a class variable then - @@project

Comment: i changed it to @@project = ... , but i still get the same error same error.

Comment: i think that is because i do not have any class surrounding this whole thing?

Comment: if you don't have a class then why do you use instance variables @accepted, etc.?

Comment: i thought the @ was required to access those variables in my view files? i based this off of a sinatra tutorial. happy to adjust in whatever way is suitable :)